# How to make custom ANR dialog in Android instead android ANR dialog

Tags: android

I want to design custom ANR Dialog so that when ANR comes, it shows our own dialog instead ANR dialog. How can I do this?

Comment: The best way to handle ANR dialogs is not to cause then in first place. Never do something the in the main thread that will take long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Android ANR dialog** is a System Handled (Generated) you don't have a any control over it..

As its implemented in System OS Source So you can't change the ANR Dialog. As you can't catch when ANR comes.

The only option is modifying the Android OS Source.

Comment: Instead of Handling ANR Dialog try to make sure your Application doesn't generate ANR. Put Lengthy operation in worker thread and keep Main UI Thread simple..

Comment: How to modify the android OS Source to control over ANR dialoge? please look into this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613709/application-not-responding-aosp?noredirect=1#comment25638489_17613709