# How to change Application Not Responding (ANR) Timeout in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, code-analysis, android-anr-dialog

How do I change the Application Not Responding (ANR) timeout in the AOSP source code? The default timeout is 5 seconds, but where is that set and how do I change it?

Comment: From experience, that is device dependent. On some devices, that is 5 seconds, but on some it is higher.

Comment: @gunar can we change it in our source code?

Comment: no way!!!! you should investigate why that happens and remove the cause, not the effect. Here's a good thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr?rq=1

Comment: @Dhasneem If you have the source for your device, then you can change it, compile and flash it. It won't help others if they encounter an ANR using your app though...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ANR Timeout is defined in File InputDispatcher.cpp (frameworks\base\libs\ui) . Copying and pasting that piece of code below.

```
// Default input dispatching timeout if there is no focused application or paused window
// from which to determine an appropriate dispatching timeout.
const nsecs_t DEFAULT_INPUT_DISPATCHING_TIMEOUT = 5000 * 1000000LL; // 5 sec
```

Comment: In my source code, there is no such file InputDispatcher.cpp. I want it for ICS source code

Comment: check in this path  frameworks / base / services / input / InputDispatcher.cpp

Comment: Ya.. I can found out. And one more doubt. For all source code, it will be there or ll it change?

Comment: @Dhasneem - Oh.. M late. Now any doubt?

Comment: Can't find where frameworks\base\libs\ui is stored... do you guys have any idea ?